# Reseed next Drupal User ID (UID)

Tags: users, database

Is it possible to modify the next User ID when creating new users in a Drupal 7 database?

As an example,

I have a user at UID 100, I then create and immediately two user accounts (101, 102). When I next add a user, I want the UID to revert to 101 rather than default behaviour of 103.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to do this? Seems a bit funny that you would add a user and then make sure it's overwritten by decrementing the auto increment value

Comment: Attempting to import User records from D6 to D7, to a D7 database that has had several test Users created (which will be deleted).

Comment: I still don't understand, what you're describing's surely impossible. If you have a table (`users`) with an auto inc value at 100, then you add 2 records, and then reset the auto inc value back to 101, it's going to clash with the existing record at id 101.

Comment: Is the auto inc the value of the next UID or is it the amount the UID increases by each time?

Comment: It's both - The value of the next ID will become the current maximum ID, + the increment (1). Thinking about it the `users` table doesn't even have an auto inc on it so I think this is all moot

Comment: Hmm... I've tried exporting the User table SQL, deleting the table and reimporting and the UID is not being reset to match the highest UID, it's higher as it's accounting for the previously deleted User accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 7 the `uid` column in the `users` table isn't an autonumber, so there's nothing to reset/reseed.

When you add a user in D7 the [`user_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) function does this:

```
// Allow 'uid' to be set by the caller. There is no danger of writing an
// existing user as drupal_write_record will do an INSERT.
if (empty($account->uid)) {
  $account->uid = db_next_id(db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM {users}')->fetchField());
}
```

So the next user ID is simply the next available free ID (current max + 1) from the `users` table.

If you have a record with a uid of 100, then you add 2 new users (101 and 102), the next available user ID will naturally/logically be 103; which will be returned by the above code in `user_save()`.

If you need that to be 101 again for whatever reason, you need to delete the user you've just created that occupies the 101 ID, and set the uid manually on the new user record that you want to replace it, before you save it (as suggested by the above comments in `user_save()`).

Comment: Apologies Clive, your answer was spot on. I missed out key information from my questions in that the users 101 and 102 have since been deleted yet the next user on migrate was 103. I have since found the 'sequences' table.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently encountered a similar need at my site and here is the way to achieve the desired behavior:

```
function MYMODULE_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {  
   $account->uid = db_query('SELECT MAX(uid) FROM users')->fetchField() + 1;
  }
}
```