# How to make user IDs start on 5000?

Tags: 7, users, database

On our Drupal 7 social network site, we want the user ID (user number) to start from 5000.
What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Just a hint: you could use [UUID](https://drupal.org/project/uuid) to not show numbers in any way. Setting it at X means someone will guess X sooner or later. Making it a semi-random hash means it is impossible to guess things like who registered earlier, how many users there is, what's the registration per day rate etc just by looking at IDs. With 5000 as a start someone may calculate: Ok, today max id is 6530, ten days ago it was 6480, it gives 50 users / 10 days. Site is up for 10 months, it gives roughly 10*30*5 = 1500 users, so it started around 5030. Well, probably 5000.

Answer (score 2):

One could modify the auto increment field of the users table in the database. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number.

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000;
```

Comment: If you look at the schema, users.uid isn't auto increment.

Comment: @MPD I can't tell when, but I'm sure it used to be... Bad memory or it was changed at some point?

Comment: It changed between 6 and 7, but I don't know why.  I suspect it has to do with making the DB layer more generic to potentially support storage that doesn't do auto increment.

Answer (score 2):

Followin [clive's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77281/reseed-next-drupal-user-id-uid), I realized that on Drupal 7, the next user ID is simply the next available free ID (current max + 1) from the users table.

There is no need to change the ID of an existing user to 5000, as [this post](http://www.werockyourweb.com/drupal-how-change-your-user-id) suggests.

So the following sequance worked:

1. Create a new record on the users table:

   `insert into users (uid, name, status, mail) 
   values (5000, 'tmp',1,'email@example.com');`
2. Register a new user throght the web. The user was added as #5001.
3. Delete the user record:

   `delete from users where uid=5000;`